# Angular 5 : How to solve "Headers not defined" error on Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: angular, angular5, internet-explorer-11

I'm getting the following error whenever Headers are used by the Angular 5 application on Internet Explorer 11.

> ERROR ReferenceError: 'Headers' is undefined

The content of the polyfills file are as follows:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
// import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
// import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

What could be done to solve this error?

Comment: I think it refers to variable undefined

Comment: can you post some snippet of actual http call?

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Getting-Started:-Install-&-Use

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed 

`code` getCustomers() {   
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const response = this._httpRequests.doGet(this.getcustomers_url, headers);
    return response;
  }  `code`

This is the format used in HTTP calls. Almost every header is not supported in IE.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else gets here, the answer for me was to use [`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) rather than `Headers` in my application.

Answer (score 0):

For me removing the headers when I make the request fix this issue for IE11:

```
getPageContent(page: string): Observable<any> {

    //let headers = new Headers({
    //    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    //});

    //let header: any = {
    //    headers: headers,
    //    responseType: ResponseContentType.Text
    //};

    return this.nssHttp.getNonStandardResponse<any>(`/api/user/GetUserPage/${page}`)
        .map(res => res.text())
}
```